# Configuracion dns VPS

Tags: servidor, dns

Estoy armando un VPS que contará con 3 servidores virtualizados usando la maquina virtual de VB.

Cada máquina tiene instalada una distribución de Ubuntu Server 14.04 que ejecuta unos servicios construidos por mí en java que escucha peticiones ciertos puertos.

Poseo una sola IP certificada, 2 dominios y un sub-dominio.

Tanto los 2 dominios como el sub-dominio apunta a la IP certificada que está adjuntada a un firewall y de allí redirijo los puertos a unos de los servidores virtuales.

Pero mi necesidad es la siguiente:

```
dominioA.com --- servidor1 (10.1.1.2)
dominioB.com --- servidor2 (10.1.1.3)
sub-dominio ---- servidor3 (10.1.1.4)
```

Como no es tráfico HTTP no puedo usar el proxy reverso de apache.

Mi duda es, como hago para redireccionar dependiendo del dominio a mis servidores (IPs) locales.

Tengo entendido que con un servidor DNS se logra eso, así que habilité una 4<sup>a</sup> máquina virtual con Ubuntu Server y bind9, me he tratado de documentar, he realizado unas pruebas y no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Así que espero que alguien con conocimientos o experiencias me arroje más luz sobre la posible solución.

Comment: ¿Cuando hablas de "IP certificada" a qué te refieres? ¿Qué tipo de firewall o balanceador es? ¿Qué cliente usas? Dependiendo de tus respuestas podría recomendarte usar SNI, soportado a partir de Java 7, pero debe soportarlo también el cliente y el balanceador.

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que ese tipo de redirección solo se puede llevar a cabo desde la capa de aplicación, metiendo algún tipo de proxy inverso que rutee la petición del cliente según una cabecera enviada por el cliente que indique el host, pero para eso los servicios tiene que hablar algún protocolo que permita este tipo de cabeceras, como http.

https://serverfault.com/questions/699226/nat-routing-based-on-dns-name-reverse-tcp-proxy/699243

Una manera de solucionarlo es hacer el ruteo por el puerto, de manera que cada servicio tenga asociado un puerto único,  y así desde el firewall puedes redirigir cada puerto a su máquina correspondiente.

`dominioX:puerto1 -> 10.1.1.2
dominioX:puerto2 -> 10.1.1.3
dominioX:puerto3 -> 10.1.1.4`